# JAR Signing Java using digital certificate

Tags: java, swing, jarsigner, jar-signing

Hope you are all doing well..

I am signing my jars for the first time and for this your genuine help is required.. problem I am facing is I do not know the steps of jar signing with trusted certificate(ssl.com) not self signed jar..

please help and let me know the steps.. please please

I tried to follow oracle doc but didn't get succeed, I want help in jar signing

Comment: Show your command line as text in code format, along with its errors

Comment: it do not have any errors. it is siging my jar but when I deploy it gives error on update java saying "Unsigned application requesting unrestricted access to system unsigned resource..."

Comment: my jarsigner is signing jars with disabled algorithms